# Unable to import shp to QGIS 3.0

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3

[image]I'm using QGIS Desktop 3.8, and unable to import a shapefile.  I get the following error:

"The layer already exists.  Are you sure you want to overwrite the existing file?"

I'm super frustrated, as I have tried installing different versions to fix the issue and I get the same message.  I just used QGIS yesterday on my work laptop and it was fine, but this issue occurred on my personal laptop as I worked from home today.

When I answer "Yes" to overwrite file, the shp shows as listed in the layers panel but is not visible in the map view.  When I try to "Zoom to Layer" there is still nothing.

Suggestions?

Comment: a couple of screenshots would help. can you right click on the layer and select 'zoom to layer'? what do you see?

Comment: @vagvaf this is the error message.  Yes, I tried zooming to layer, nothing.  There is nothing in the attribute table, either, even though I've downloaded the shp fresh from 2 different sites to make sure it wasnt the shapefile that was corrupted.

Comment: The message is about a **new** layer, i.e one that is being created from scratch, so it is understandable that its content is initially empty. Maybe you want to **add** the existing layer. Note that if you have overwritten it, it is now lost and you would need to re-download it.

Comment: a simple drag and drop is the easiest way to add a shapefile

Comment: Are you trying to create new shape file or adding a shape file? Regards
Ashok

Comment: From your question, it looks like you want to import an existing shapefile and dont want to create a new one. Have you tried using **data source manager** to import it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and still don't know what happened exatcly, but for me it worked when I added the layers from the Navigator menu on the left side. Just right-clicked the shapefile, selected "Add layer to the projetct"*  and it worked.

*Free translation from the pt-br version of QGis, don't know how it is displayed in the english version.

[image]